Maven - single way to know if tests are skipped
With Maven, there is more than one way to skip running unit and/or integration tests.
For example:

mvn clean package -DskipTests  (Tests are compiled, but not run)
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip (Tests are neither compiled nor run)

If I'm trying to activate a profile based on the fact that tests are being skipped, how could I reliably do that?
I can activate a profile based on absence of one property, but not two:
    <profile>
        <id>do-something-because-tests-are-skipped</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!skipTests</name>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>!maven.test.skip</name> <!-- Two properties doesn't work -->
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
        .....
        </build>
    </profile>

Is there some other way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Can you give some more details why you like to activate a profile in such cases?

@khmarbaise I'm configuring some build output when for when the tests run, which is noise when the tests are skipped. In particular, there's some extra (external) postman tests and also when building for docker, where it is helpful to not have this output configured.

This has now been implemented in Maven 4.0.0-rc-1
<profile>
    <id>do-something-because-tests-are-skipped</id>
    <activation>
        <condition>
            <![CDATA[
                not(${skipTests}) && not(${skipITs}) && not(${maven.test.skip})
            ]]>
        </condition>
    </activation>
    <build>
    .....
    </build>
</profile>

